# Visual Studio with Resharper. Code editing will not respond to keyboard after running Windows System Restore

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, system-restore

I ran a windows system restore on my Windows 7 PC
Now when I open my visual studio solutions in VS2015 Update1 , when I type into the source code, no changes are accepted.

I can create new projects, and I can open the source files in notepad.

I have tried restarting the computer.

The problem disappears if I uninstall Resharper Ultimate 10, and re-appears if I reinstall it.

Visual Studio About shows

```
    Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015
Version 14.0.24720.00 Update 1
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.6.00081

Installed Version: Professional

Visual Basic 2015   00322-40000-00000-AA025
Microsoft Visual Basic 2015

Visual C# 2015   00322-40000-00000-AA025
Microsoft Visual C# 2015

Visual C++ 2015   00322-40000-00000-AA025
Microsoft Visual C++ 2015

Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio Package   1.0
Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio

ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015 (RC1 Update 1)   14.1.11120.0
ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015 (RC1 Update 1)

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2012.2   4.1.41102.0
For additional information, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=309563

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2013   5.2.30624.0
For additional information, visit http://www.asp.net/

Azure App Service Tools v2.7.1   14.0.11112.0
Azure App Service Tools v2.7.1

Common Azure Tools   1.5
Provides common services for use by Azure Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.

CreateLayoutWizard   1.0
Create layout wizard.

DevExpress.DeploymentTool   1.0
A useful tool for deploying DevExpress assemblies.

DevExpress.ExpressApp.Design.DynamicPackage   1.0
DevExpress VSIX Package

DevExpress.ExpressApp.DesignPackage   1.0
DevExpress VSIX Package

DevExtreme.Design   15.2.4
DevExtreme Visual Studio integration package

JetBrains ReSharper Ultimate 10.0.2   Build 104.0.20151218.120627
JetBrains ReSharper Ultimate package for Microsoft Visual Studio. For more information about ReSharper Ultimate, visit http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper. Copyright © 2016 JetBrains, Inc.

Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Tools   1.4
Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Tools

NuGet Package Manager   3.3.0
NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit http://docs.nuget.org/.

Open Command Line   2.0.163
Opens a command line at the root of the project. Support for all consoles such as CMD, PowerShell, Bash etc.

PreEmptive Analytics Visualizer   1.2
Microsoft Visual Studio extension to visualize aggregated summaries from the PreEmptive Analytics product.

SQL Server Data Tools   14.0.50616.0
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

TypeScript   1.7.6.0
TypeScript for Microsoft Visual Studio

XtraReports package   1.0
XtraReports package
```

Comment: Are they marked read-only?   (notepad can open read-only files).

Comment: They are not marked read only. 
I tried undoing the system restore but the problem remains.

Comment: Updated to show Resharpers effect

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/641783/visual-studio-stops-responding-to-keyboard-input

Comment: https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2015/07/23/critical-issue-with-resharper-9-1-2-in-visual-studio-2015-rtm-workarounds-and-estimates/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try deleting `%LocalAppData%\JetBrains\Transient` folder where R# stores caches for Shell and a solution.